# The “iden” column should contain the individual number for each member of the group

Tags: r

if petal. width is o.1 then my new column value should be 1 :n number like wise it has ti  print for every unique values

```
`data=iris
data=data[order(data$Petal.Width),]
count=1
data$iden<-with(data,(data$Petal.Width))
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
if(data$Petal.Width[i] == data$Petal.Width[i]){
 count=count+1 }}`
```

Comment: its not works @akrun

Comment: its showing like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, to 121 but i need 1:n number for particular group

Comment: Can you show your expected output.  I updated the solutioin

Comment: wait i will show the expected output

Comment: Can you please check the output I shared

Comment: You are showing a subset of the data.  Please check my output

Comment: thanks @akrun but i have a another problem based on the  same dataset

Comment: Can you telll me the isssue

Comment: same @akrun now instead of printing the seq it should be print like if 0.1 means it should be 1 if 0.2 it should be 2 if 0.3 it should be 3

Comment: That would be my earlier solution i..e `with(data, match(Petal.Width, unique(Petal.Width)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create the sequence with `ave` from `base R`

```
data$Seq <- with(data, ave(seq_along(Petal.Width), Petal.Width, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data$Seq <- rowid(data$Petal.Width)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(Petal.Width) %>%
     mutate(Seq = row_number())
```